# bazel run error: no such target '//slim:public'

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

When I follow this instruction: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/domain_adaptation
and run:

```
> $ bazel run slim:download_and_convert_data -- --dataset_dir $DSN_DATA_DIR --dataset_name=mnist
```

I got this error:

```
chenshuo@ubuntu:~/research$ bazel run slim:download_and_convert_data -- --dataset_dir ./data --dataset_name=mnist
ERROR: /home/chenshuo/research/slim/BUILD:71:12: no such target '//slim:public': target 'public' not declared in package 'slim' defined by /home/chenshuo/research/slim/BUILD (this is usually caused by a missing package group in the package-level visibility declaration).
ERROR: /home/chenshuo/research/slim/BUILD:69:1: no such target '//slim:public': target 'public' not declared in package 'slim' defined by /home/chenshuo/research/slim/BUILD and referenced by '//slim:download_and_convert_data'.
ERROR: /home/chenshuo/research/slim/BUILD:69:1: no such target '//slim:public': target 'public' not declared in package 'slim' defined by /home/chenshuo/research/slim/BUILD and referenced by '//slim:download_and_convert_data'.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//slim:download_and_convert_data' failed; build aborted.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.286s
ERROR: Build failed. Not running target.
```

How do I fix this error? Thanks.

#### System information

- **What is the top-level directory of the model you are using**: `~/research$`
- **Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow)**: No
- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04)**: Linux Ubuntu 14.04
- **TensorFlow installed from (source or binary)**: source
- **TensorFlow version (use command below)**: 1.3.0
- **Bazel version (if compiling from source)**: 0.5.2
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**: cuda-7.5
- **GPU model and memory**: GeForce GTX TITAN X
- **Exact command to reproduce**:

Answer (score 2):

Change [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/1464a721fef7da67e87b0f1f1a710b1e904e8764/research/slim/BUILD#L4) from:

```
package(default_visibility = [":public"])
```

to:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
```